# Keycloak: Bypass an authenticator flow

Tags: java, authentication, oauth-2.0, keycloak

I have two `UsernamePasswordForm` classes as the `authenticators`

`SampleUsernamePasswordForm` and `SecurityUsernamePasswordForm`

If SampleUsernamePasswordForm is a success, there is no need to move to `SecurityUsernamePasswordForm`, but if there is any credential error, I want to bypass `SampleUsernamePasswordForm` authenticator and move to `SecurityUsernamePasswordForm`

Both are under `ALTERNATIVE`  right now, which means if one if a failure, it should move to the next one

In `SampleUsernamePasswordForm`, I tried

```
if (!validateForm(context, formData)) {
        Response challengeResponse = challenge(context, getDefaultChallengeMessage(context), FIELD_PASSWORD);
        context.failureChallenge(AuthenticationFlowError.INVALID_CREDENTIALS, challengeResponse);
 }
```

and

```
if (!validateForm(context, formData)) {
        context.failure(AuthenticationFlowError.INVALID_CREDENTIALS);
 }
```

I thought calling context.failure on this would trigger `SecurityUsernamePasswordForm`, but it just shows error message on the same login form

Currently, I had to resort to where I had to place login from `SecurityUsernamePasswordForm` in `SampleUsernamePasswordForm`, which doesn't look neat. How do I skip to  `SecurityUsernamePasswordForm`?

Also, for some reason, the `SampleUsernamePasswordForm` object is created 3-5 times before `authenticate` gets called , is this something which can happen with Authenticators?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that both executions are ALTERNATİVE, you would just call attempt
on SampleUsernamePasswordForm to just pass to next execution(SecurityUsernamePasswordForm). But just make sure that at-least one failure or success must be returned end of the flow.